# How can I close off crawl space vents for the winter?

Tags: insulation

My exterior air vents are still letting air into the crawl space, even after being closed for the winter. I've seen the suggestions for wedging plywood over the air vents to further block the air, but is there a product such as a solid metal cover that goes over the closed air vent (from the outside) to more successfully insulate the crawl space? I've searched online and can't find anything. I'm wondering if it's because I don't know the specific name for such a thing. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your *louver* (damper; shutter) doesn't  work so well anymore. Replace the whole thing with one made out of metal that has rubber seals where the blades contact: ([solerpalau-usa.com](http://www.solerpalau-usa.com))

[image]

A working louver should not leak (much) air or need an extra cover, however you may want to shove insulation or foam board in it, for over the winter. A custom cut-to-fit foam board taped-to it on the inside, may be a cheap temporary solution.

FYI, a vent cover with movable lovers is also a *register*. One without movement is a *return grill*, or simply a *grill*.

---

If your grills are metallic and relatively flat, you can use a **magnetic vent cover**: ([always-free-shipping.com](http://www.always-free-shipping.com/magnetic-vent-covers.html?cmp=googleproducts&kw=magnetic-vent-covers&utm_source=GoogleShop&utm_medium=cse&utm_campaign=magnetic-vent-covers&gclid=Cj0KEQiAm_eiBRCWgIfq9pK1nZsBEiQAGqUcSSXrpZjUTxKxrklA75qQymGOjrMWMacWfiYlFaCbHW4aAo0I8P8HAQ))

[image]